# Security breach: PHP file edited on codeigniter site, ubuntu server

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, malware

I run a file sharing site, built on Codeigniter, PHP 7.
We recently found one of the files in our www/application/controllers dir was very slightly edited to change a download request for 1 in every 3 Windows users, which pointed them to a malware file instead (which had been uploaded to our server legitimately) 
The SSH access is locked down with a private key which only I have.
The dir/file permissions were possibly not great at the time, maybe 755 or even 777.

I'm trying to figure out how a file that isn't in a public directory was edited when I'm fairly confident they couldn't have obtained SSH access.

Are there any known vulnerabilities with CodeIgniter that would allow this?

Comment: Try [security.se] for this—they probably know better than we do.

Comment: shared hosting? try running CI above root